# How can I transfer clicks in from one Qt Widget to another?

Tags: c++, qt, mouseevent

I'm trying to create a pseudo remote control widget, the remote control widget (an overridden QLabel) receives a screenshot (pixmap) of the widget to be controlled every 2 seconds or so through a REST api. I've overridden the QLabel mouse events and can store the positions of clicks on the overridden QLabel.

How can I convert these positions into mouse events and execute them on the "remote controlled" widget?
I've attached the cpp of the overridden QLabel and would appreciate any input.

```
#include "RemoteControlLabel.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QMouseEvent>

RemoteControlLabel::RemoteControlLabel(QWidget* parent) : QLabel(parent)
{

}

RemoteControlLabel::~RemoteControlLabel()
{

}

void RemoteControlLabel::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
    QPoint pos = event->pos();
    qDebug() << "mouse pressed at " << pos;
}

void RemoteControlLabel::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
    qDebug() << "Mouse released";
}
```

Comment: Does the api have an endpoint for mouse clicks? what parameters does that expect?

Comment: hard to know what is the Remote control expecting as event?  does it get an event? or a button? or the coordinates of the click?

Comment: The api is expecting the coordinates and an enum depicting the type of click (press,release,drop). I'd like to convert these into mouse events if possible but I CAN change the Api to accept mouse events if I have to.

Comment: You probably need to translate the mouse click coordinates into the REST commands.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
virtual void RemoteControlLabel::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event) override
{
    QPoint pos = event->pos();
    qDebug() << "mouse pressed at " << pos;
    // create new event on the stack
    QMouseEvent event(QEvent::MouseButtonPress, pos, 0, 0, 0);
    // use sendEvent - it sends the event directly
    QApplication::sendEvent(remotelyControlledWidget, &event);
    // at the end of scope event will be automatically deleted, which is our intention
}
```

Comment: This seems to work though the receiver does not execute the event. What do I need to do to make sure they execute the event?