# How to redirect a click into a widget to the QMainWindow?

Tags: c++, qt

How I could redirect the click inside a determined widget to the QMainWindow?

When 'redirected' the click would not be executed into the widget, only in the QMainWindow.

Some things I tried:

```
   void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
    {
        if (x)
            // process the click into the widget
        else
        {
            // Redirect the click in the same position to the QMainWindow
            QMainWindow *mainWindow = qobject_cast<QMainWindow*>(window());
            if (mainWindow)
                  mainWindow->raise();

            setAttribute( Qt::WA_TransparentForMouseEvents );
            qApp->processEvents();
            setAttribute( Qt::WA_TransparentForMouseEvents, false );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do not do qApp->processEvents() in event handler or even better never do that. And maybe you need this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63789944/how-can-i-transfer-clicks-in-from-one-qt-widget-to-another

Comment: You may be looking for [`installEventFilter`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qobject.html#installEventFilter)